# Kidnapper? Some Spacing needed

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

### Prologue

You are coming home from work, happy with your current coding progress (you are a coding and maths prodigy), but then you get kidnapped...

You wake up after some hours of sleep in the kidnappers car boot.
You see a over hundred of doors and in big red writing the words "Only **1** door leads to freedom!"

### Puzzle

You find a laptop that has a big text file open.

```
Have fun with this puzzle...
You are the only one that can solve this!
There are several layers of encryption used. You might need some spacing where you are relative to your beginning!


Wu mdk vplv rtsiqinzz wi, hwue mdk ogu wc hwu zpik dwqjw.

Gdbmw hwyj apjy djpqdx hd gjc wi oab ie, 
rd hwu zpik giug kxjy hwu ocinwkm, 
oct hwue ztqmw ihyey hwu b-jy rdei, 
kxjy b ptyey hwu ocinwk hd hwu djpqdx. 

vijgk://w.giqtc.wbwlj.qdc/JHsuS.xew

Mdk vplv 1 rpo.
```

**Note:** I created my own program to encrypt it (one program each for every layer of encryption), so it is possible that, there are some mistakes! Doing it by hand would be to tedious :P And if you have decrypted it post a comment saying you have decrypted it (There is a timer in the email that you will see by decrypting it)

### Hints

Hint 1:

> "You might need some spacing where you are relative to your beginning": What is almost always seperated by spacing? Apparently the cipher has to do something with, where its parts are relative to its beginning.

Hint 2:

> Refering to Hint 1: Words are seperated by spacing. They are made of letters...

Hint 3 (only use if you have already decrypted the text):

> Each row is independant. Every row follows the same rule though.

**BIG HINT**: Hint 4 (only use if you have already decrypted the text):

> ***Every*** row is built like this:

> ```
>  +----------------+
>  | x | y | answer |
>  +----------------+
>
>  Where x is one digit, y is one digit and
>  answer is made up of two digits.
> ```

> Try and find out how to get from x and y to answer.
>  The rule is the same for all rows

Hint 5 (only use if you have found out, what the "?" stands for):

> "To ***sum* it all up**" (view decrypted text)

> And view the first spoiler tag of hint 4 again.

Comment: I have decrypted it.

Comment: hmm, it looks to be easier than Enigma,  for much the same reason,  but I am no Alan Turing.

Comment: Already Decrypted? That was quick...

Comment: I will add a hint for those that haven't decrypted it yet

Comment: Does anyone still need a hint?

Comment: Only to solve the square.

Comment: @z100 Have you gotten the question mark?

Comment: 3rd row, 4th column.

Comment: @z100 Have you found out what it is?

Comment: Some number from zero to nine.

Comment: @z100 I have added hint 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open the

> 70-th door if sumarize all 4 the so called "answers" from the math puzzle described below.

Text is encrypted, each word separately, using Vigenère Cipher with key "NOPQR...", first letter shifted by 14, 2nd by 15, 3rd by 16 and so on. Easy to see from words the, you and https. Decrypted Text:

> If you have decrypted it, then you are in the last phase. Solve this math puzzle to sum it all up do the last step with the answers and then leave using the n-th door with n being the answer to the puzzle.

> [image: puzzle] "You have 1 day."

Puzzle explanation:

> Twice the sum of first two columns is equal to the number in last two columns, so $2\times(0+8)=16$ and $6$ is the question mark solution.   (in fact I solve the system of equations $3x+2y+1z=0 and so on) Using BIG HINT it means 16 as the "answer" based on 2nd spoiler of Hint 4 is the door number.

Comment: Almost done! One more step remaining... Great job though. **Note:** _I didn't use Vignere Cipher, I don't know what that is, but it is very likely that I could have used a Vignere Cipher to do the same encryption. The decrypted text is correct_

Comment: I added a hint 5, for this last step, that you need to do